# AWS - How to expose multiple API endpoints with one lambda function

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have the following `Lambda` function:

```
using Amazon.Lambda.Core;

// Assembly attribute to enable the Lambda function's JSON input to be converted into a .NET class.
[assembly: LambdaSerializer(typeof(Amazon.Lambda.Serialization.Json.JsonSerializer))]

namespace AWSLambdaAPI
{
    public class Function
    {

        /// <summary>
        /// A simple function that takes a string and does a ToUpper
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input"></param>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public object FunctionHandler(string input, ILambdaContext context)
        {
            return new { FirstName = "William Smith" };
        }
    }
}
```

Im using `AWS Gateway API` to create a POST call to this Lambda function.

My quesiton is: Is it possible to user only one Lambda function to expose multiple API methods? Or I have to create one Lambda for everymethod I want to expose.

> For example: If I have a method that will validate login and then other method that will insert some objects into S3, can I do that in a single Lambda function?

Comment: Did you ever find a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a single API gateway endpoint to handle different methods but it depends on the use case. They are:

1. If all the methods that you have are working is in a flow i.e one after the other you have two options:

   - Go with **AWS step functions** that will execute different lambda functions in a sequence [AWS Step function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/welcome.html). So we can trigger the lambda function with an API gateway and you can order the lambda functions to execution in sequence. Then we just need a single API gateway to trigger your all lambda functions which will be executed in a sequence specified by us. But the **drawback** is that, if we what our AWS step function to return something we have to **poll** every time to see that status whether its in running state or it has finished. **AWS Step function runs async** way so it will give us the required response when it has fineshed execution.
   - Other option can be like **one lambda function** which will call a function from within which is a normal function. Let's say, in your example, your first method is the login one. So if you want your lambda function to login first and then insert an object to S3 you can go for a single lambda function which will have the login functionality and if its ok then it will call a function which will handle the object to be sent to S3. This technique is used my many people but we need to track the total jar size that we upload. AWS Lambda has some limits on the size of the jar we upload. [AWS Limit](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html).
2. If the above situation doesn't suit you then you have to go for **different lambda functions** for each method.

> Note: Please don't link different lambda functions directly. It is not the right approach. Use AWS Step function instead.